# Creating generic class' constructor with additional type constraints

Tags: java, generics, constructor, type-parameter

I want to create DataSets for use in algorithm testing.
I have a generic wrapper class that holds data of type T as well as information about the arbitrary size/complicatedness of the dataset to be able to map input-size to runtime.
Since not everything I want to test on will simply be multiples of something, I do not want to constrain T.
However I'd like to have a constructor that 'recognizes' something as a Collection and can then infer the size itself.

Below code does work, but has a compiler warning for a good reason
or needs to throw an Exception respectively.

```
public class DataSet<T> {
    private final long size;
    private final T data;

    public DataSet(T data, long size) {
        this.data = data;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public <I extends Collection<?>> DataSet(I input) { //allows for DataSet<String> foo = new DataSet(List.<Integer>of(1, 4, 6);
        this.data = (T) input; //compiler warning / ClassCastException: unchecked cast I to T
        this.size = input.size();
    }

    public DataSet (T input) {
        if(!(input instanceof Collection)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input needs to be Collection"); //either this or a ClassCastException later
        }
    
        this.data = input;
        this.size = ((Collection<?>) input).size();
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public long getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Both work if used correctly, but allow for mistakes as well, since I'm not sufficiently able to describe to the compiler what I want allowed there ('T is the same as I' or 'T needs to extend Collection in this Constructor only').

So; How do I define a constructor that can put constraints on its Class' type parameter(s) without introducing new type parameters for itself or the class and with compiler support for usage?

Comment: Well, I bit the bullet for now and created a subclass, the type parameter of which needs to extend Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is split you implementation on 2 child, something like:

```
public interface DataSet<T>{
    T getData();

    long getSize();
}

class SimpleDataSet<T> implements DataSet<T>{
    private final long size;
    private final T data;

    public SimpleDataSet(T data, long size) {
        this.data = data;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public long getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}

class CollectionDataSet<I> implements DataSet<Collection<I>>{
    private final Collection<I> data;

    public CollectionDataSet(Collection<I> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Collection<I> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public long getSize() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

But if cannot do it, you can try to do the following:

```
  public <I> DataSet (Collection<I> input) {
        this.data = (T) input;
        this.size = input.size();
    }
```

Or

```
private final Collection<T> collectionData;
public DataSet (Collection<T> input) {
        this.data = null;
        this.collectionData = input;
        this.size = collectionData.size();
    }
```